# Layout of multiple items of the same field in Panels node template

Tags: views, entities, panels

My content type is a preview of a music album so the fields include mp3 file and text fields about the track (title etc). I am using a panels node template which looks like this [image: panels screenshot]

This works fine for one track and the result looks like this:

[image]

But if I add a second track it looks like this:

[image]

ie

All items in Field 1
All items in Field 2
All items in Field 3

How can I make it look like this:

[image]

ie

field 1 item 1
field 2 item 1
 
field 3 item 1
field 4, item 1

field 1 item 2
field 2 item 2
 
field 3 item 2
field 4, item 2

etc

I think I would have the same problem in Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your content type and Use a [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection). instead of multiple fields. It's difficult to achieve what you want without explicit entities.

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.

`Field collection` will allow you to add multiple fields into one group, so instead of adding data to each field, you can just keep adding groups of data.
This will allow you to add a collection of **Artist, track number, track title, mp3** Then when you call the `field collection` via panels it will give you the results you want.

You are using multiple fields which will list the values from each individual field right underneath eachother.

Comment: @ DMAC ok thanks - after looking at https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection I have also come across https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield which does a similar job - do you have any opinion about https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield ?

Comment: Multi-field is not as mature as field collections in terms of what it can do, but it is a good solution if you do not have multiple value items inside the multi-field. You can have a multiple value multi-field, but not multiple values inside the sub fields inside the multi-field, if that make sense. I've never used multi-field before, field collections does everything I want. And paragraphs combined with field collections can pretty much do anything.